# Javascript - Using cookies to store an integer

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am trying to use a cookie to store a single integer, so when the user refreshes the page I am able to retrieve the previous number they were on (in an attempt to stop doubles of a video appearing).

What would the minimum requirements be to accomplish this?

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);

document.cookie=(randomNumber);
```

Setting a cookie:

```
document.cookie = 'mycookie=' + randomNumber + ";max-age=" + (300) + ";";
```

Reading a cookie:

```
var cookie = document.cookie;

alert(decodeURIComponent(cookie));
```

The cookie contains some other random stuff like push=1 as well as mycookie. Should I be setting the cookie to null before I add the randomNumber?

As far as getting the value of mycookie would I just assign the cookie to a string and parse mycookie from it?

Comment: Check http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html to set and retrieve cookie values in javascript. Use javascript `parseInt` once you retrieve the value of your cookie

Answer (score 2):

Tamil's comment is solid. Use these quirksmode functions if you ever wish to surpass minimal cookie usage:

```
cookie_create = function (name,value,days) {
    var expires, date;

    if (days) {
        date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";

expires = date = null;
};


cookie_read = function (name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=",
    ca = document.cookie.split(';'),
    len = ca.length,
    i, c; 

    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1); //,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length); //,c.length);
    }

nameEQ = name = ca = i = c = len = null;
return null;
};


cookie_erase = function (name){
    cookie_create(name,"",-1);
name = null;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [document.cookie](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) to read/write cookies in javascript:

```
document.cookie = 'mycookie=' + randomNumber + '; path=/';
```

And if you wanted the cookie to be persistent even after the user closing his browser you could specify an `expires` date.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Just working on reading/parsing the cookie now :P