# How to set in Angular 4 cookies, type number values

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies, session-cookies

I'm beginning to develop in angular 4 with typescript. I want to save info in cookies. I'm using "[ngx-cookie](https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie)". Put method, just accept for the value as type string and I want to save a number type var. What the best approach for that?

**Explanation found**
[Javascript - Using cookies to store an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272331/javascript-using-cookies-to-store-an-integer)

Cookies in browsers are strings, that seems the reason

Comment: welcome. Please read [**Asking Help**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking any question

Answer (score 1):

In typescript you can use the 'any' type to store values to get around being specific with strong types.

```
var myInteger: any;
var myString: any;

myInteger = 1 //valid
myString = "helloWorld" //valid
```

As ngx-cookie put method takes a string you would need to pass a string. I would call JSON.stringify on your object and pass that to the put request.

```
saveSearchCritereaCookie = new myCookieObject();
var searchCookie: String = JSON.stringify(saveSearchCritereaCookie);

* @param {string} key Id for the `value`.
 * @param {string} value Raw value to be stored.
 * @param {CookieOptions} options (Optional) Options object.
 */

put(key, searchCookie, options?): void;
```

Please see the ngx-cookie documentation page for more examples: [NGX-Cookie](https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie#options)